# Extending Spinner cannot click

Tags: android

When i click on Default Spinner, it shows popup.
Then extend Spinner to add some feature, but it doesn't respond at all to my touch. When i click on it, nothing happend and the popup not shown

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayOf("Aaoeuaoeuaeu", "Baoeuaoeuaoeu", "Caoeuaoeuaoeu", "Daoeuaoeuaoeu"))
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        spinner.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

**SpinnerCustom.kt**

```
class SpinnerCustom @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : Spinner(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.pln.customspinnerwithlabel.SpinnerCustom
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```